# How to assign to a class property of type Func<>

Tags: c#, func

Alright, so I have a class. In that class I have the following property:

```
private Func<object, OutputEventArgs> _outputMethod = null;
    public Func<object, OutputEventArgs> OutputMethod
    {
        get { return _outputMethod; }
        set { _outputMethod = value; }
    }
```

I want the class to be able to invoke this method which is going to allow it to send outputs (error messages and the like) to somewhere of my choosing.

That seems to work alright, but the issue comes when I want to assign that property.

I have another class called OutputHandler which looks like this:

```
public static class OutputHandler
{
    public static void HandleOutput(OutputEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm aware I could just call that method directly from the class in question, but I want to enforce some kind of separation of concerns.

So my assignment is like this (c1 being an instance of the class with the Func in it):

```
c1.OutputMethod = ????
```

I've tried a few things, but none of them work. I've also looked up and down this site and come up with nothing so far.

Comment: `public static void HandleOutput(OutputEventArgs e)` is not a `Func<object, OutputEventArgs>` but an `Action<OutputEventArgs>`

Comment: `Func<TResult>` Means it is going to return a value of type `TResult`. I think you meant to use `Action<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have mentioned, you can change your OutputMethod to an Action instead of a Func, *or*  you can change:

```
public static void HandleOutput(OutputEventArgs e)
{

}
```

to

```
public static object HandleOutput(OutputEventArgs e)
{

}
```